# Routing external calls to api with out a domain name

Tags: asp.net, api

I have a client that does api calls to a owin server. When calling e.g. http://192.168.345.13:8000/api/status it works fine when doing this from a local machine on the same LAN as the server.

When using the same aurelia client from a remote machine e.g. a 4g smartphone then the client code is shown but the api calls don't work. My router forwards the port to the server machine so external ip a.b.c.d:8000 routes to the server.

This is ofcourse because the client has hardcode : http://192.168.345.13:8000/api/status.

My question is how do i support both local and remote via the same API? Can i detect this in the client code?

Can i detect a remote ip and switch to external ip (a.b.c.d:8000/api/status)?

Any sugestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that had some old ip filtering on. After disabeling this it works now. Using the external ip for the server the server ip calls.

When on the local network i use the local machine ip in the browser and when accesing from e.g. 4g Phone  then i use the external ip.